# How to shift post date (add x days) programmatically in Wordpress? Changing bulk post date in a function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have thousands of posts scheduled for the next 5 months; 500 posts per day to publish. Want to spread it into the next 20 months by publishing 125 posts per day.

So, we might need to run a db query and get all the posts scheduled for the next 5 months. Then for each specific date, we need to add 150 days to 125 posts, 300 days to the next 125 posts, 450 days to the next 125 posts, and just leave the last 125 posts to get published in the next 5 months.

Need to do it programmatically since doing it manually in Phphmyadmin takes forever.

I'm not familiar enough with $wpdb class and php; so your help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Even if you wanted someone else to write this for you ___which is not the purpose of SO___. You have not given enough information. At SO we help you fix code, we dont write it all for you

Comment: Didn't give more information like exact start date and end date of the scheduled posts because I don't expect anyone to write the whole code for me to just copy and paste! That was not the intention; thank you though.

Comment: Something to think about while you formulate your question.., http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c0955/3

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figured this out. Since it's only 5 months, wrote the code below and run it 5 times:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i < 30) {

    //Adding '0' to the dates lower than 10 to make them look like how it's saved in DB; 2018-12-01 00:00:00
    $i_string = $i;
    if ($i < 10) {
        $i_string = '0'.$i;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    //Updating 125 post date per each date from September to the corresponding date in January, June and November 2019
    for ($j = 1; $j < 12; $j+5) {
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
            "UPDATE wp_posts 
            SET post_date='2019-0$j-$i_string 00:00:00', post_date_gmt='2019-0$j-$i_string 08:00:00' 
            WHERE post_date = '2018-09-$i_string 00:00:00' 
            AND post_type = 'post' 
            LIMIT 125;"
        ));
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Took me only a few minutes to run it 5 times and get what I wanted. But I'm not going to accept my solution since it doesn't work for someone who might need to change the dates for many months!